# Disable temporarly the automatic video repaint of the video renderer

Tags: video, mfc, directshow, repaint

Here is my problem. I have some docking panes at the left side of SDI/MFC app. At the center of a CView there is my video (using VMR9 or EVR). When I close the docking panes, the framework automatically repaints the CView content moving my video at the left side of the client area. Then I reposition my video to move it back to the new center (client area with docking pane closed).

This method produce flickering, since the video seems to move rapidly a little. So, here my question. Is there any way to disable the repaint method of the video renderer  temporarly so, I can black-erase the entire screen and then reposition my video at the middle of the client screen ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Flickering is caused by erasing area behind video during resize. You would want to prevent from this by handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` on the hosting windows, esp. excluding video rectangle from erase operations, and suppressing default erase handlers.

Comment: I handle WM_ERASEBKGND but this is not the problem. As I said, VMR9 or EVR renderer under DirectShow, overlay the video layer above any View at the center of that hanged view. When I resize the view, the DShow Video Image does not update automatically the position of the video layer. So the video layer loose it's aligment to the center. When I immediately enforce to align the video layer it seems that it moves a little to the left or the right analogous to the current situation (docking panes are expanded or closed).